# How to fix Couldn't open connection to jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://etc\nQuery mode must be specified

Tags: java, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to create a Kafka-connect Source Instance using a rest API.
I keep getting the above exception.
I post this Connection information (Not including password)

```
{
    "name": "example-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
        "tasks.max": "10",
        "topic.prefix": "mytopic",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@exampleConnectionString,cn=OracleContext,dc=world",
        "connection.user": "example_user",
        "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter"
    }
}
```

Assume the connection information (not provided here) is correct, I also make sure to have to the ojdbc7.jar driver in the

```
usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/
```

directory of my container (where I attempt to post the message). 
That same connection information allows me to connect to the database with a client application.  What am I missing?

Comment: You need to match JDK version with Oracle version with JDBC driver version. More details in [interoperability matrix](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_02). Also, I have no experience with kafka but the JDBC connection URL you posted doesn't look correct to me.

Comment: It isn't correct.  I am not posting the connection string works with a client DB application tool (Like SQL Developer or SQL Squirrel).  So I know it isn't the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error that you get:

`Query mode must be specified`

tells you the problem :) You are missing `mode` from your config. If you want to pull in the entire contents of a table each time use `"mode":"bulk"`. For more details see [this article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector#incremental-ingest).

Comment: Thanks Robin.  I think I have seen you on official Kafka Confluence Web Posts.  Glad my question could garner your interest.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know where one can find a list of ConnectorTypes would you?  Making a curl request against a get http://localhost:8083/connectors/kafka-connect-jdbc/config/validate or http://localhost:8083/kafka-connect-jdbc/config/validate returns a 404 and I am still not able to establish a connection.

Comment: Happy to help :) You can get a list of currently loaded plugins at https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/references/restapi.html#connector-plugins

Comment: If you want a list of available connectors in general, try http://hub.confluent.io, or https://www.google.com/search?q=kafka-connect

Comment: I don't think running a get to any of those connectors will return anything as I don't think the connector has been instantiated with the post call.  It is always failing, I am not sure why

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking. `GET /connector-plugins/` will return all the currently loaded plugins (connectors). There's no definitive list of every single `ConnectorType` out there. But if you want to see what connectors are available for different technologies, see Confluent Hub.